# How to split data from list with more than 1 data and append bellow to Data frame - PYTHON - pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I did this code to extract data from pdfs and create a list in excel with  'number of PO' / 'Item' / 'Data' / archive name. But when the pdf has more than once the number of PO and item, this data is appended with a list within a list. Its ok but when I put the lists to dataframe pandas, it creates a list with more than one data and I need to split the data and include in a new column below in order.

```
lista_Pedido = []

lista_Data = []

lista_Item = []

nome_arquivo = []

for f in os.listdir():

    col_3 = [f]

    nome_arquivo.append(col_3)
    
    reader = PdfReader(f)
    page = reader.pages[0]
    pdf_atual = page.extract_text(f)
    
    col_1 = re.findall(r'\w+(?<=PO: 45)\d+',pdf_atual)
    lista_Pedido.append(col_1)
    

    
    col_12= re.findall(r'(?<=Item )\d+',pdf_atual)
    lista_Item.append(col_12)
    
    col_2 = re.findall(r'[?<=(Date of delivery:  )|?<=(Data de fornecimento:  )]\s+\d+/+\d+/+\d+',pdf_atual)
    lista_Data.append(col_2)


df = pd.DataFrame(data=(), columns=['Pedido','Item','Data'])

df['Item'] = (lista_Item)
      

df['Data'] = (lista_Data)

df['arquivo'] = (nome_arquivo)
```

Wrong result = list with more than 1 data, I need to splite e append below following the order of a list

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1W3Y.png)

Comment: please add the imports,  `pandas as pd`, `import os` . . . . https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting a list of lists is because `re.findall` returns a list. If you would like to add the results as individual results you can do the following.

```
col_1 = re.findall(r'\w+(?<=PO: 45)\d+',pdf_atual)
lista_Pedido.extend(col_1)
```

Or:

```
col_1 = re.findall(r'\w+(?<=PO: 45)\d+',pdf_atual)
for result in col_1:
   lista_Pedido.append(result)
```

Comment: It was very usefull, It worked very well and I finished my code!! Thanks!!